# Graph not coming out as expected

Tags: d3.js

I am expecting a graph based on the below, but it seems my graph is repeating a small portion over and over again for some reason. I can't figure out where in the code I'm going wrong here- see below:

```
var dataset = [];
var xScale, yScale;  
var w=300;
var h =150;

//Load in the data
d3.csv("movies.csv", function(row) {
    data = []
    data[0] = parseFloat(row.Rating);
    data[1] = parseInt(row.WinsNoms);
    data[2] = parseInt(row.IsGoodRating);
    dataset.push(data);
    //console.log(data)

    var svg= d3.select("body")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("width",w)
               .attr("height",h);
    svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d){
         return d[0];
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d){
         return d[1];
       })
       .attr("r",5);
});
```